# .ScrollLeft in Firefox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, scroll

I have this script:

```
<script>
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".thumbs  div"), function ($div) {
        $div.style.width = document.querySelectorAll("   img").length * 100 / 4 + "px";
    });
    document.querySelector("#next").onclick = function () {
        var i = 100;
        var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
            document.querySelector(".thumbs").scrollLeft += 1;
            if (i == 0) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            }
            i--;
        });
    };
    document.querySelector("#prev").onclick = function () {
        var i = 100;
        var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
            document.querySelector(".thumbs").scrollLeft -= 1;
            if (i == 0) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            }
            i--;
        });
    };
</script>
```

That scrolls the slider thumbs when clicking the next or prev buttons. In Opera and Chrome, it works fine - with one click to the button, `.thumbs` scrolls 100px. But in Firefox, with one click, it scrolls 1px.

What can I do to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you aren't passing an interval delay to `setInterval`, and so Firefox only runs it once. Other browsers seem to take it as if you were passing it `0` (the minimum delay).

Just pass `0` or any value you like, to both of your intervals.

http://jsfiddle.net/ar8au1o6/1/

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
    document.querySelector(".thumbs").scrollLeft += 1;
    if (i == 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
    i--;
}, 0); // <-- Set each interval in your code to 0, 
       // Or any other delay.
       // If you set it to 0, the browser will pick the minimum delay.
```